# python chatbot , integrating the chat bot to website

Tags: python, html, css

i have created a chatbot on my own and trying that chatbot to be implimented in my website. i need the answers of the chat bot in a specific feilds of my html page. how can i do it please some one help me. i have used flask api also.

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
import random
import json
import nltk_utils
import torch
nltk.download('punkt')
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

from nltk_utils import bag_of_words, tokenize, stem
from model import NeuralNet

with open('intents.json', 'r') as f:
    intents = json.load(f)
```

Comment: What "html webpage" are you trying to manipulate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of WSGI implementation. Since you're still starting, I would recommend you use [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/). It will help you to receive responses and reply back. From Flask you can use the `jsonify` function to return the parameters in the format you want.